# Interface is fading but alert dialog is not shown

Tags: android, dialog

I have an `Activity` which will show an `Alert Dialog` after seconds. Before dialog being shown, immediately I press the **Home** button. Again if I go back to my application, interface is fading but alert dialog is not shown (i.e visible). If I press the **Back** button and cancel the pop up, my `Activity` is active again.
The question is, why the dialog pop up but not be shown? How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858047/alert-dialog-shown-but-not-visible may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    While creating your alert try 

    Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(currentActivity);
    alertDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                WMLP.x = 0;   
                WMLP.y = 0;  
                WMLP.dimAmount = 0.0f;
                alertDialog .getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```